# Live site blank in frontend or keep on loading and never load

Tags: apache, magento, session, server, browser-cache

I am facing Strangest Problem ever in magento.  we are using 1.9.0 version.

from last 5 days, our live site is "blank" or "keep on loading" for used browsers. Means in this browser we visited the site lot of times.

in some browsers, its working fine. in some showing blank.

but **backend** is working fine in all browsers.

1)If we clear the browser history[cache and cookies], than its working.

2)If we open the same site in private window , its working.

3)If we open the site in freshly installed browsers, its working for some time. again blank after we used the site.

4)If we clear the var/session folder, than it will start to work for all browsers for some time. again site blank.

5)sometimes, site will be keep on loading and it will never load....

I checked **system.log & exception.log** . but seems there are no errors related to this. we are using **https for secure** pages. even we have live **Andriod app** for this site. sometimes we will get Fatal errors  :

```
**Fatal error**: 
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes) 
in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php or lib/Varien/Object.php 
or /lib/Varien/Db/Select.php or app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php

we set memory_limit = 1512 Mb in php.ini
```

in **.htaccess** we have following files.

```
php_value memory_limit 1512M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

we uncommented this :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

but no error displaying in frontend. This is **apache error** log :

```
child pid 23845 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Really struggling to solve this problem. Is this problem related to our code or is this problem related to server side ?

Comment: Cross-post => http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88243/live-site-blank-in-frontend-or-keep-on-loading-and-never-load

Comment: @FiascoLabs as this is live site, i dont have any option as i need solution immediately.

Comment: I'm assuming that there's something in your code causing a massive memory leak causing you to run out of memory. What you'll need to do is try and monitor the memory usage and find out which pages is causing the highest loads. Then you can narrow your search and find the offending code. What are your server specs? As it could just be purely your server too, have you done any optimisations? Such as enabling APC/Memcached, etc?